# Finding a polynomial formula for sequence of numbers

Tags: python, math, sequence

I was wondering if there is a way in Python (or any language for that matter), where I can supply a list of numbers and I get back a polynomial of smallest degree that results in that list of numbers.

E.g. If I supply the sequence `1,4,9,16` I should get back `n**2` or `n^2`.

Comment: Thanks pal. Well i dont have a particular sequence in mind, i just wanted to know if i could supply a bunch of numbers and out would pop a formula (yes a poly in the least degree) and if so, the high level logic of how this could be coded. Eg i supply 1,4,9,16, without already having a list of 'popular' sequences, is there a way of coding that would output n^2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can code a routine yourself using the `sympy` module in Python. (This is a popular third-party module for Python.) This code uses the base formula for the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition), the polynomial of smallest degree that yields a given sequence. This code allow you to define your own `x`-values in addition to the `y`-values: if you do not define the `x`-values, this routine will use `1, 2, ...`. Note that there are other ways to get this polynomial--I used the formula used in Wikipedia in the link.

```
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')
zeropoly = x - x
onepoly = zeropoly + 1


def lagrangepoly(yseq, xseq=None):
    """Build a Lagrange polynomial from a sequence of `y` values.
    If no sequence of `x`s is given, use x = 1, 2, ..."""
    if xseq is None:
        xseq = list(range(1, len(yseq) + 1))
    assert len(yseq) == len(xseq)

    result = zeropoly
    for j, (xj, yj) in enumerate(zip(xseq, yseq)):
        # Build the j'th base polynomial
        polyj = onepoly
        for m, xm in enumerate(xseq):
            if m != j:
                polyj *= (x - xm) / (xj - xm)
        # Add in the j'th polynomial
        result += yj * polyj
    return sympy.expand(result)
```

With that routine, executing `print(lagrangepoly([1, 4, 9, 16]))` gets the printout

```
x**2
```

which is `x^2` in Python notation.

Comment: This helped me a lot in an Advent of Code puzzle - cheers.